# How to draw text on desktop?

Tags: delphi, windows-7

I need to draw a scrolling text directly on desktop. I can draw text on top of all windows using DC := GetDC(0). But I don't want that. The drawing has to be on desktop only, and not on top off all open windows. My text needs to be below the icons on the desktop!

How ca I do this in Delphi? I guess Windows 7 has new API functions to allow easier access to desktop window this since it can fade the wallpaper.

Comment: If you don't want your text to stay below the icons on the desktop, the window with the fading wallpapers is irrelevant.

Comment: Hi Sertac. Can you detail this?

Comment: The window with the wallpaper is beneath the window having the icons (SysListView32), that's all I meant. If you write on to anything other than a DC acquired for the desktop (progman, workerw, shelldll_defview etc..), your scrolling text will stay beneath the icons on the desktop. Providing the text on its on window as David says would be easier.

Comment: "The window with the wallpaper" - Yes. Yes. That's what I need. How do I get a handle to that window?

Comment: I believe it would be the `WorkerW` (not sure), but it only appears when wallpaper rotation is active. Search for 'workerw' and you'll find lots of code samples that use `FindWindow[Ex]` to get a handle... Use Spy++ or alike to find out the window hierarchy of the desktop when wallpaper rotation is active and when it is not, show/hide them to findout which one has the desktop background. Dunno, something like this..

Comment: This used to be possible with "active desktop" in windows 98 era. (You could put an object onto the desktop itself).

Answer (score 8):

This has been possible for a long time with [layered windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx). Use the  `WS_EX_LAYERED` and `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` window states. You will want to ensure that the z-order of the window puts it underneath all other top-level windows. The article I link to has a number of code samples to get you going.

---

After I added this answer you added a further requirement that the text be drawn beneath the icons on the desktop. I suspect that this is not possible with layered windows since layered windows cannot be child windows.

Comment: Hi. I haven't fully read the documentation but it says "provides an efficient way to add transparency and translucency to top-level windows". I want to paint on desktop so my text stays there also when my application is not running. For example Microsoft's Wallpaper Slideshow tool offers a smooth transition between two images. And the image stays there even if the tool is not running.

Comment: You can use layered windows to achieve what you want. The key is `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` which makes the window click-through.

Comment: But the text I draw using this method will above icons not below.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to paint on desktop so my text stays there also when my application is not running.

If the text should also be there if your app is not running then your only option is to change the wallpaper: find out what the image of the desktop wallpaper is, add your text to that image and save it as a new wallpaper and use that one.

Comment: I agree with that. But is it possible to change the wallpaper without sending the REFRESH message to all windows in the system. It seems that Microsoft's Wallpaper SlideShow is doing exactly this.